# MobileConnect Opt-In with surrogate Keyword

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have an `PROMO` keyword which I use as the attached keyword for all my new Marketing SMS messages. I send emails to customers to allow them to Opt-In to these SMS promotions, currently they have to text the exact Keyword `PROMO` to sign up, but this is difficult to track when I have multiple campaigns pushing the same keyword.

I wanted to know if it's possible to setup setup a new keyword such `OFFER2020` which instead of opting them into `OFFER2020` opts them into `PROMO`. The reason for this is so I can have individual signup keywords for each campaign and can track which campaigns users are signing up to the generic PROMO keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't configure the Mobile Opt-in template in Mobile Connect to be triggered by a different keyword than the one you want to subscribe them to.

To achieve this you would need to a text new interactive text message (Text Response template on your `OFFER2020` keyword) that will use ampscript to write the data about this customer (SubscriberKey found with a lookup to your database, phone number and locale) to a data extension

Next you would need to create an import definition in Contact Builder that will opt-in contacts from this data extension to your `Promo` keyword.

---

You could probably also do with Ampscript if you could find an API call that creates a mobile subscription.